# Avoiding "/mnt/" while calling sudo chown -R in "Ubuntu on Windows"

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Ubuntu on Windows.

I want to take ownership all of the files and folders in the current user profile.

To do that, I call

```
sudo chown -R USERNAME /
```

It works, but it also tries to chown all files in folders under "/mnt/".
This means it tries to work on all my Windows folders as well.

I don't want that.

How could I process only the files and folder in the user profile?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you know what you are doing? I'm afraid you will render your Ubuntu non-functioning with that.

Comment: Yes, I want to try something.

Comment: Then I'd like to recommend that you set up a virtual machine with Qemu or VirtualBox, install Ubuntu there, and destroy that one. ;-)

Comment: What happens if you `umount` all Windows drives? Please note that I don't use Windows, it's just an idea.

Comment: @thebusybee Thank you, I will try that. I didn't know that I could do this. Seems to be the solution to my problem. Also, I am working with an installation that I may destroy. I simply uninstall Ubuntu on Windows and install it again.